# Different assets location for development and production for Angular 8 app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Suppose I have multiple ***img*** tags in my Angular 8 project. And I need the path for those images to be different when I build the app for production. For example, if I have the following in html template while working on the project locally

```
<img src="assets/image1.jpg" />
```

I need it to become

```
<img src="images/image1.jpg" />
```

for the production version. Using `--baseHref` and `--deployUrl` does not help.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the proposed solutions do not work for me. I tried changing `angular.json` but that still doesn't solve the problem as `<img src="assets/myfoldername/img1.jpg />` still includes **assets** part!

Since I'm incorporating Angular app into my ASP.NET Core 3.0 project and host it with IIS, I used IIS URL rewriting rule and now everything works. So no adding a dummy app, no usage of any environment variables in angular app. **Just one rewriting rule**. Done.

PS. I will use URL Rewriting Middleware in my ASP.NET Core so this will work on any OS and web server.

Answer (score 1):

just set a variable in environments then use it accordingly

eg,:
environment.ts:

```
imagePath: /images
```

environment.prod.ts:

```
imagePath: /assets
```

then you have to import environment in your .ts file and use the variable in the path

Answer (score 0):

Create a secondary app profile for your production build and configure the assets to output to whatever folder you wish. You can also just duplicate the outputs in your single build profile so they get outputted to multiple locations.

Configuring Multiple App Profiles: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps

Assets Configuration: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-asset-configuration

```
"assets": [
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/output/" }
]
```

Next just use environment files to store the path per build and use that to bind to your `<img [src]="myImageVariable"/>`

Answer (score -1):

I think the only solution for this is to use [Multiple Apps integration](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps#multiple-apps-integration) :

in your `.angular-cli.json`  add a new app for production

```
"apps": [
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "main": "main.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
    "test": "test.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app",
    "assets": [
     "src/assets",
   ]
  },
  {
    "root": "src",
    ...
    "main": "main2.ts",
    "polyfills": "polyfills2.ts",
    "test": "test2.ts",
    "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
    "prefix": "app2",
    "assets": [
     "src/assets2",
   ]
  }  
],
```

Later on when serve/building :

To serve the first app: `ng serve --app=0` or `ng serve --app 0`

To serve the second app: `ng serve --app=1` or `ng serve --app 1`

Comment: and I get this whatever I do with __assets__ section:

```
<img _ngcontent-nvx-c2="" src="../assets/img/service-cart-1.jpg">
```
with `.../assets/img/...`. The **img** part is correct but not other. No way to get rid of __assets__.